# floating text over image ..how to align it to the right

Tags: css

I am trying to float some text (prices) over images. The images are always the same width and height, but the text may be different length. So I'm trying to keep always the same space on the right side and expand the text towards the left as needed. For some reason, I can't make it work. It always expands floating out of the box to the right. Any ideas?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="productphoto">
<img src="photo.jpg">
<div class="pricetag">$1959.99</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.productphoto { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}
.pricetag { 
   position: absolute;
   top: 190px; 
   left: 190px; 
   text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to position your `.pricetag` relative to right, not left:

```
.pricetag { 
   position: absolute;
   top: 190px; 
   right: 10px; /* NOT left: 190px; */ 
   text-align:right;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VQDWy/)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I spent an hour trying to find out what's wrong, haha :) Thanks for helping a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:
    
        
    
    
        Text
    
CSS:

```
.image {
    float: left;
}
.text {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/Hxcgs/